# Form validate with jquery then send by ajax to php

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, input, conditional-statements

I have a little problem, I have bootstrap form with bootstrap validator plugin and also ajax post script. My problem is, that I don't know how to set a conditions, which I have to reach to enable submit button.

I want to set my submit button default disabled, and if every input will be filled (with bootstrap validator conditions), then javascript can allow to click on submit button.

Thanks for you answers.

Here is my code:

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#requestquote').bootstrapValidator({
     message: 'This value is not valid',
     group: '.form-overenie',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            name: {
                message: 'Zadané meno nie je správne',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Prosím zadajte svoje meno'
                    },
                }
            },
            company: {
                message: 'Zadaný názov je neplatný',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Prosím napíšte názov spoločnosti'
                    },
                }
            },
            phone: {
                message: 'Zadané číslo je neplatné',
                validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                        min: 9,
                        message: 'Zadané číslo je príliš krátke'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Prosím zadajte svoje telefónne číslo'
                    },
                }
            },
            mailovaadresa: {
                message: 'Zadaný email nie je správny',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Prosím zadajte svoju emailovú adresu'
                    },
                }
            },
            projecttype: {
                message: 'Zadaný názov je neplatný',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Prosím zadajte typ projektu'
                    },
                }
            },
            budget: {
                message: 'Zadaný názov je neplatný',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Prosím zadajte približnú výšku rozpočtu'
                    },
                }
            },
            projectdescription: {
                validators: {
                 
                }
            },
        }
    });
});



jQuery(function () {

        jQuery('#requestquote').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'forms/requestquote.php',
            data: jQuery('#requestquote').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              jQuery("#uspesne-odoslane").show();
              jQuery(".formular-potvrdit").hide();
              jQuery(".formular-riadok").hide();
              jQuery(".formular-zavriet").hide();
            }
          });
        });

      });
</script>
```

```html
<form id="requestquote" action="forms/requestquote.php" method="post" style="width:85%;margin:0 auto;">
       <div class="formular-riadok">
        <fieldset><div class="form-overenie" style="float:left;"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Meno" class="input-lava" /></div>
        <div class="form-overenie" style="float:right;"><input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Spoločnosť" class="input-prava" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="formular-riadok">
        <div class="form-overenie" style="float:left;"><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telefón" class="input-lava" /></div>
        <div class="form-overenie" style="float:right;"><input type="email" name="mailovaadresa" placeholder="E-mail" class="input-prava" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="formular-riadok">
        <div class="form-overenie" style="float:left;"><select name="projecttype" class="input-lava" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Typ projektu</option>
         <option value="webstranka">Web stránka</option>
         <option value="eshop">E-shop</option>
         <option value="portal">Portál</option>
         <option value="forum">Fórum</option>
         <option value="seo">SEO</option>
         <option value="korporatnaidentita">Korporátna identita</option>
         <option value="logo">Logo</option>
         <option value="ine">Iné</option>
        </select></div>
        <div class="form-overenie" style="float:right;"><select name="budget" class="input-prava" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Rozpočet</option>
         <option value="do500">do 500 €</option>
         <option value="500az1000">500 € - 1 000 €</option>
         <option value="1000az3000">1 000 € - 3 000 €</option>
         <option value="3000az5000">3 000 € - 5 000 €</option>
         <option value="5000az10000">5 000 € - 10 000 €</option>
         <option value="10000az20000">10 000 € - 20 000 €</option>
         <option value="nad20000">nad 20 000 €</option>
        </select></div>
        </div>
        <div class="formular-riadok">
        <div class="form-overenie" style="display:block;"><textarea name="projectdescription" placeholder="Stručný popis projektu" class="formular-textarea"></textarea></div>
        </div>
        <div class="formular-riadok" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <span class="formular-zavriet" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvoriť</span>
        <button type="submit" class="formular-potvrdit" disabled>Odoslať</button></fieldset>
        </div>
        
        <div id="uspesne-odoslane" data-dismiss="modal" hidden><h3><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Správa bola úspešne odoslaná</h3></div>
      </form>
```

I disabled my submit button, but when I click on sumit, ajax will send data, when any input is filled.

While I had only first part of script, everything was OK (it allow me to send form only if every input was filled), but when I added ajax, if I fill just one input, it will send the form to php...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using:

```
data: jQuery('#requestquote').serializeArray(),
```

Serialize() will give you something like a query string